# AlarmManager plays only default ringtone

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I'm creating an alarm using AlarmManager and PendingIntent. The alarm works and is triggered at the correct time. Unfortunately, it always plays the default ringtone, regardless of what ringtone I have selected. This is my code:

```
public void setAlarm() {
    Cursor cursor = dataBaseHelper.showSpecificTableData(DBFields.TABLE_OF_ALARMS, DBFields.ALARM_STATUS, "On");
    cursor.moveToLast();

    String alpha[] = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBFields.ALARM_TIME)).split(":");

    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(alpha[0]));
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(alpha[1]));
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    Intent intent = new Intent(AddAlarm.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("AlarmTone", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBFields.ALARM_TONE)));
    intent.putExtra("AlarmId", cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBFields.ALARM_ID)));
    intent.putExtra("AlarmName", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBFields.ALARM_NAME)));
    intent.putExtra("AlarmTime", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBFields.ALARM_TIME)));
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),
            100,
            intent,
            FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}
```

I have used debugger and I know that the correct ringtone is put into the Intent as an "AlarmTone" extra.

Any idea why the selected ringtone isn't playing

Comment: Did you try unstalling the app and reinstall it?

Comment: I'm running the application in Android Studio on an emulated device.

Comment: It doesn't matter. You can still try it.